# gcc doesn't include debug symbols when compiling with library

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols

I've run into a strange problem with gcc not producing debugging symbols, and would really appreciate some help.

Granted, I'm probably doing something stupid here, but I havent forgot -g or -ggdb, and I haven't snuck a -s in there either. Here is the info:

I have a static library called list (it's a school assignment), and two programs including it in different ways.

In main (compiled to `fifo`) list is included as `#include "list.h"`, whereas in prodcons, it is included as `#include "list/list.h"`
When I run gdb on the compiled file `prodcons` I get the message "no debugging symbols found"
the same goes for the compiled `fifo` file. according to the `file` command, neither files are stripped.

File structure:

```
.
├── list
│   ├── list.c
│   ├── list.h
│   ├── main.c
│   └── Makefile
├── makefile
├── prodcons.c
```

.o files and binaries excluded for clarity.

Here are the make files:
list/Makefile:
    all: fifo liblist.a

```
OBJS = list.o main.o 
LIBS= -lpthread

fifo: ${OBJS}
    gcc -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS} -ggdb

liblist.a: list.o
    ar rcs liblist.a list.o

clean:
    rm -rf *o fifo
```

./makefile:

```
prodcons: prodcons.o 
    gcc -g -static -Wall -I./list -L./list -o $@ prodcons.o -llist -lpthread

clean:
    @@rm prodcons prodcons.o
```

So, any gurus out there, ready to perform their magic? :)

Comment: Which versions of gcc and gdb?

Comment: The line for your final executable (fifo) is getting passed -ggdb, but it is not very useful there since it is the linking step. Debug info is generated at the compilation step for each compilation unit. When list.o and main.o are compiled (from list.c and main.c), it looks like they are not passed -ggdb, so the debug info is not generated. An option would be to define CFLAGS="-ggdb -O0" (debugging with optimization enabled is a... strange experience). The default build rule for %.c -> %.o will pick up CFLAGS and pass the flags to all your compilation units. Same goes for prodcons.

Comment: If you still don't get debug symbols please check the output of `nm --debug-syms your_executables_name`. See also [nm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Simply adding the CFLAGS to list/Makefile solved the problem for both executables. Not sure I get it, but thanks. You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Bishop: gdb 7.6.1-1, gcc 4.8.2-3.

Answer (score 1):

You should first compile the lib with `-g` option and then link the .o file into libraries, somehow like this:

```
list.o: list.c
     gcc -c -g list.c -o fax.o
liblist.a: list.o
     ar rcs liblist.a list.o
```

the use this static lib to compile others.